# Cannot increase the change of opaque value of track in android Switch

Tags: android, android-switch

How can I increase the opaque of track in Switch Android .
I have used style as below .
But the opaqueness is not 100% when the switch is on .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#66FFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

Style

```
 <style name="style_switch" >
        <item name="android:trackTint">@drawable/selector_switch_track</item>

    </style>
```

Switch Code

```
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/style_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    >

</Switch>
```